# Calling method from an AngularJS Controller in SSRS Report

Tags: angularjs, reporting-services, rdlc

I created an angularJS Controller with 1 method.

**Controller.js**

```
var project = angular.module('project',[]);
project.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.run = function(){
      alert('Test');
   };
});
```

I created a placeholder in a textbox in SSRS RDLC. I changed the placeholder properties. From General pane, I selected **HTML-Interpret HTML tags as styles** under **Markup type** section. Then, under **Value**, I entered this: **="< a onclick='run()'> Run Report < /a>"**

However, it did not work. Is it possible to call an javascript method that was implemented in an AngularJs controller in SSRS RDLC??

Answer (score 0):

user **ng-click** instead of **onclick**

Comment: Will the SSRS Report recognize the ng-click property?